# How upload a video to Youtube Using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to use Google Apps Script to upload a video YouTube using the YouTube Data API v3. This is my code:

```
function YouTubeAPI()
{
  var url = {URL VIDEO};
  var file = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob();
  Logger.log(file.getName());
  var snippet = {
  "snippet": {
    "title": "Summer vacation in California",
    "description": "Had a great time surfing in Santa Cruz",
    "tags": ["surfing", "Santa Cruz"],
    "categoryId": "22"},"status": {"privacyStatus": "private"}};
  YouTube.Videos.insert(snippet, 'snippet,status', file)
}
```

The response is "Unauthorized", I check the Google Console is enable, and in the Script also enable the Youtube Data API.

Comment: See new answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an MP4 file in your Google Drive that is less than 50MB, then you can get the file from your Google Drive and upload it to YouTube using the YouTube Data API.  I created a new Google Cloud Platform (GCP) project, and enabled the YouTube Data API and the Google Drive API, and associated the new GCP project with my Apps Script project.  Also, I manually added the needed scopes to the appsscript.json file.

```
{
  "timeZone": "Your time zone will be here",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "YouTube",
        "version": "v3",
        "serviceId": "youtube"
      }
    ]
  },
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube"],
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

The code:

```
function uploadToYouTube(mp4_fileId) {
  var blob,mp4_fileId,part,requestResource,response;
  var options = {},snippet = {};

  /*
    You will need to create a GCP standard project and associate it with this Apps Script project-
    In the new code editor click the settings cog wheel and scroll down to:
    Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Project -
    You may get an error:
    In order to change your project, you will need to configure the OAuth consent screen. Configure your OAuth Consent details.
    
    And if you do not have a Google Workspace account then you wont be able to set up the GCP project as "INTERNAL"
    You will need to enable the Google Drive API and the YouTube API in the associated GCP project -
  */

  /*
    This code needs the file ID of the MP4 file in your Google Drive - 
    To get the file ID of an MP4 video file in Google Drive, right click the MP4 in your Google Drive
    and choose, "Get link"
    The link will look like this:
    https://drive.google.com/file/d/FILE_ID_IS_HERE/view?usp=sharing
    In the URL is the file ID
  */

  options = {
    "method" : "get",
    "headers" : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    "muteHttpExceptions":true
  }
  
  mp4_fileId = mp4_fileId ? mp4_fileId : 'PUT_YOUR_MP4_FILE_ID_HERE';

  const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/` + mp4_fileId + `?alt=media`;
  response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  //Logger.log('response.getResponseCode(): ' + response.getResponseCode())

  if (response.getResponseCode() !== 200) {

    return;
  }
  
  blob = response.getBlob();
  //Logger.log('blob.getName(): ' + blob.getName())

  /*
  {"snippet":{
    "playlistId":"YOUR_PLAYLIST_ID",
    "position":0,
    "resourceId":{
      "kind":"youtube#video",
      "videoId":"abcdefg"
      }
    }
  }
  */

  /*
  {
  "snippet": {
    "title": "Summer vacation in California",
    "description": "Had fun surfing in Santa Cruz",
    "tags": ["surfing", "Santa Cruz"],
    "categoryId": "22"
  },
  "status": {
    "privacyStatus": "private"
  }
  }
  */
  
  requestResource = {};

  snippet.title = "AAA_Put_Title_Here";
  snippet.description = "Description of video goes here";
  snippet.categoryId = "22";

  options.snippet = snippet;
  options.status = {
      "privacyStatus": "private"
    }

  part = "snippet,status";//This correlates to the options

  //YouTube.Videos.insert(resource: Youtube_v3.Youtube.V3.Schema.Video, part: string[], mediaData: Blob, optionalArgs: Object)
  var response = YouTube.Videos.insert(requestResource, part, blob, options);

  if (!response || !response.kind) {//There was an error
    console.log("Error!")
  }
  
  //Logger.log('response: ' + response);

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use [code below](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/apps-script#update_video). This sample code finds the user's uploads then updates the most recent upload's description by appending a string.

```
/**
 * This sample finds the active user's uploads, then updates the most recent
 * upload's description by appending a string.
 */
function updateVideo() {
  // 1. Fetch all the channels owned by active user
  var myChannels = YouTube.Channels.list('contentDetails', {mine: true});
  // 2. Iterate through the channels and get the uploads playlist ID
  for (var i = 0; i < myChannels.items.length; i++) {
    var item = myChannels.items[i];
    var uploadsPlaylistId = item.contentDetails.relatedPlaylists.uploads;

    var playlistResponse = YouTube.PlaylistItems.list('snippet', {
      playlistId: uploadsPlaylistId,
      maxResults: 1
    });

    // Get the videoID of the first video in the list
    var video = playlistResponse.items[0];
    var originalDescription = video.snippet.description;
    var updatedDescription = originalDescription + ' Description updated via Google Apps Script';

    video.snippet.description = updatedDescription;

    var resource = {
      snippet: {
        title: video.snippet.title,
        description: updatedDescription,
        categoryId: '22'
      },
      id: video.snippet.resourceId.videoId
    };
    YouTube.Videos.update(resource, 'id,snippet');
  }
}
```

For more information, download the demo app here: https://github.com/youtube/api-samples