# Can we Create Youtube Videos using Google Apps Script and upload them?

Tags: api, google-apps-script, automation, youtube, build-automation

I want to create a youtube video based on web results every 24 hours using Youtube data Api and Google Apps Script.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66963569/using-blogger-api-can-we-create-quizzes-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also see StackOverflow post:
[How upload a video to Youtube Using Google Apps Script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40987147/how-upload-a-video-to-youtube-using-google-apps-script?rq=1)

The YouTube API uploads a video to YouTube using:
Videos : insert
See:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert

Apps Script has two options for running Videos : insert.

- Advanced YouTube Data API Advanced Service
- REST YouTube Data API

If you use the Advanced Service, then you don't need to configure the OAuth verification yourself.
The REST API requires the use of `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options)`

The basic line of code for the Advanced Service is:

```
YouTube.Videos.insert(part: string[], mediaData: Blob, optionalArgs: Object);
```

The actual YouTube video needs to be a Blob.  It is possible to create a video in name only, and then upload the blob in a separate step using the `update` method.